# Removed a value in array comparing to multiple array

Tags: php, arrays

Got multiple arrays of IDs. Wanted to compare and remove the ids after I compare it with the original array.

```
$origialArr = [4883,8438,8468,4001,8577];
$arr = [
 [8438,8468,4001,8577],
 [4883,8438,8468,4001,8577],
 [4883,8468,4001,8577],
 [4883,8438,8468,4001,8577],
 [4883,8438,8468,4001,8577],
]
```

Numbers or Ids that are not in `$arr` should be removed from the `$originalArr`.
What I've tried so far, but not working and cannot get rid of 4883 and 8438:

```
// attempt 1
$arr1 = [];
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    $arr1[] = array_intersect($origialArr, $item);
}

// attempt 2
$anotherArr = [];
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    foreach ($item as $id) {
         $anotherArr[] = array_filter($origialArr, function($origArr) use ($id) {
              if ($id === $origArr) {
                   return $id;
              }
         });
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
[8468,4001,8577]
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `4883` and `8438` both are different arrays, what's the logic behind to remove these two, if you would explain so I can try.

Comment: @KamranAllana so the arrays of `$arr`  will compare to the `$originalArr` array, if the number is missing or removed from `$arr` then remove the number from the `$originalArr`. Did you get what I mean? Thank you

Comment: `foreach ($arr as $item) $origialArr = array_intersect($origialArr, $item);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your first attempt was almost there.  If you take a cumulative approach instead:

```
$arr1 = $origialArr;
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    $arr1 = array_intersect($arr1, $item);
}
```

or, if you want to be really compact about it:

```
$arr1 = array_reduce($arr, 'array_intersect', $origialArr);
```

Produces `$arr1 = [8468, 4001, 8577];`

Comment: ahh so just the variable that I'm missing. That makes sense. Thanks a lot!